# Neo4j Cypher Batch Query passing node label and property key dynamically( via the parameter list of maps)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create nodes using labels and property keys dynamically retrieved from a `$batch` parameter list.

I expected this to work:

```
UNWIND $batch as row
MERGE (s:CAR:row.label {row.key: row.value})
```

Each `row` looks something like: `{label: 'typeA', key: 'Mileage', value: 20}`

Right now, the query is working only if the label and key are statically typed. It is not accepting dynamic values for labels and property keys key. Dynamic values are only working for property values.

That is, it works only if the query is:

```
UNWIND $batch as row
MERGE (s:CAR:typeA {Mileage: row.value}
```

Any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the [apoc.merge.node](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.node/) procedure which allows for dynamically specifying node labels and properties:

```
UNWIND $batch as row
CALL apoc.merge.node([row.label], apoc.map.fromValues([row.key, row.value]);
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without using apoc?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.